# Dynamic arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, dynamic, matrix

i am beginner with c++ and i need to make a program to multiply two matrices. I already understand the array of array concept in order to make a dynamic matrix. The problem that im an facing after a make and fill the matrix is that i cannot access it. it suddenly stops when i run the program and just finished filling the second array with the function:

```
void read_matrix(int** matrix, int row, int col)
{

cout << "Enter a matrix\n";

matrix = new int*[row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[col]; 

if (!matrix){
    cerr << "Can't allocate space\n";
}

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }
}
}
```

but according to my compiler, after the program stops there is an arrow pointing after the last loop of this function

```
void multiply_matrix(int** matrix1, int rows1, int cols1, int** matrix2, int rows2, int cols2, int** result)
{

for(int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < cols2; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < rows2; k++){
            result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

my main function is

```
int main ()
{

//matrices and dimensions
int rows1, cols1, rows2, cols2; 
int **matrix1 = 0, **matrix2 = 0, **result = 0; 

//TODO: readin matrix dimensions
cout << "Enter matrix dimensions \n";
cin >> rows1 >> cols1 >> rows2 >> cols2;

if(cols1 != rows2){
    cout << "Error!";
    terminate();
}

    //memory for result matrix
    result = new int*[rows1];
       for(int i = 0; i < rows1; i++)
       result[i] = new int[cols2];


// Read values from the command line into a matrix 
read_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1); 
read_matrix(matrix2, rows2, cols2);     

// Multiply matrix1 one and matrix2, and put the result in matrix result
multiply_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1, matrix2, rows2, cols2, result);

print_matrix(result, rows1, cols2);

//TODO: free memory holding the matrices

return 0;   

}
```

i can not get why it does not work. what i think is there is something wrong in the way i fil the matrix or o do something wrong in the way i send one matrix from one function to the other.

Thanks,

David

Comment: You might understand dynamic arrays, but you don't understand parameter passing. `void read_matrix(int** matrix, int row, int col); ... int **matrix1 = 0; ... read_matrix(matrix1, rows1, cols1);` does **not** change the value of `matrix1`. The change happens inside the `read_matrix` function, the value of `matrix1` in main is entirely unaffected. It's still `0` even after you have called `read_matrix`.If you want a function to return a value then use `return`, or use references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're not allocating the `result` matrix.

Your second problem is that you're not allocating the other matrices either.

The `read_matrix` assigns the allocated memory to the parameter you pass it.
Unfortunately, that parameter is a *copy* of the pointer in `main`, so the effect is local to the function.

To fix it, you can pass a reference to the variable you wish to assign to:

```
void read_matrix(int**& matrix, int row, int col);
```

or, better, just return the correct value from the function:

```
int** read_matrix(int row, int col);
// ...
matrix1 = read_matrix(rows1, cols1);
```

On a side note: you only need to input two dimensions - if the first matrix is M x N, the other must be N x M.

Comment: Thanks a lot molbnilo! i had read about it, but not thought that this was the case. With the "&" in the function and the whole program works! but i still have a question, in order to understand what is happening i wrote "cout << "\n" << matrix1[rows1][cols1];" a the end of the program; and as it gives me the successful multiplication it crashes at this line, why is that?

Comment: @DavidKester You're indexing outside the arrays, which causes undefined behaviour. In this case, you're lucky and it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating your `result` matrix anywhere, so your `multiply_matrix` function is dereferencing a null pointer and writing to random memory.

Comment: you are right, i forgot that, but it also gives me error when i try this in the main

cout << matrix1[1][2];

Comment: @DavidKester Maybe you're accessing a cell that's outside the bound of the inputted row, column?

Comment: I added the memory for the result matrix

Comment: What values are you supplying for rows1, cols1, rows2, cols2?

Comment: Enter matrix dimensions 
2 2 2 2
Enter a matrix
1 1 1 1
Enter a matrix
2 2 2 2
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
kill
Current language:  auto; currently c++
quit

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (incorrectly) allocating and (not) deallocating your memory manually, you should use either `std::array` or '`std::vector` for your arrays.  Since you are pulling in the matrix sizes dynamically, that would lead you to `std::vector`.

**Simple example:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++)
{
    std::vector<int> row;
    for (int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++)
    {
        row.push_back(RECORD[i][j]);
    }
    matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

There are ways to do it in a single line of code as well, but I'll leave it like this to demonstrate the basic idea.